# "could not find/install babel plugin 'proposal-decorators':" codesandbox

Tags: reactjs, plugins, codesandbox

I am working with a react app locally and when i deploy it to **codesandbox** it appears this error:
could not find/install babel plugin 'proposal-decorators': Cannot find plugin 'proposal-decorators' or 'babel-plugin-proposal-decorators'

I already tried to add the dependency but it doesn't let me.

this is really important, does anybody know what might be happening?

Comment: can you please add you package.json to check your deps ?

Comment: the  @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators appear  in depedencies section or devDependencies ?

Comment: @YassineCHABLI in devDependencies as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators